# Orthogonal matrix decomposition of symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

If matrix `mat` is symmetric, we should be able to decompose it into eigenvalue matrix `matJ` and orthogonal matrix `matS` so that

```
mat==matS.matJ.Transpose[matS]
```

> `True`

Consider an example

```
mat = {{a,b},{b,c}};
```

The routine in Mathematica that does such a decomposition is [`JordanDecomposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JordanDecomposition.html), so that

```
{matS, matJ} = JordanDecomposition[mat];
mat == matS.matJ.Inverse[matS] // Simplify
```

> `True`

However, this routine does not seem to take into account that `mat` is symmetric, and so returns a not orthogonal matrix for `matS`. Is there a way to get an orthogonal matrix `matS` from mathematica (so that `Inverse[matS]==Transpose[matS]`) in cases when `mat` is symmetric? (It seems for numerical matrices `mat` the routine [`HessenbergDecomposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HessenbergDecomposition.html) gives orthogonal matrix `matS`, but what about the analytical case?)

Comment: Have a look at `Eigensystem`. Moreover eigenvectors are usually not normalized for symbolic input matrices (in order to reduce the complexity of the output).

Comment: I would have done it with: 
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat];
Inverse[vecs].DiagonalMatrix[vals].vecs // FullSimplify (You might need an extra transpose if the matrix isn't symmetric.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: If the matrix is numeric, and has distinct eigenvalues (no multiplicity) then normalizing the eigenvectors will give the desired `matS`.

Comment: You really don't want to use JordanDecomposition on numeric symmetric matrices, because if the matrix has repeated eigenvalues then it will be epsilon-close to matrices whose eigenvectors don't form a basis.